# How to get NHibernate forward all sql queries as strings through my function?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, nhibernate

I have a distributed module based system. It has DB service (wrapper) that receives strings and uses MySQL as backend. On my SQL client service side I have some interface for it like:

```
interface IDbDriver
{
   void Connect(string adress, string dbName, string login, string pass);
   void Send(string query, Action<string> callback);
}
```

How can I make NHibernate use my `IDbDriver` implementation to send commands to the DB, or how to create some wrappers for NHibernate to use my DB service wrapper?

Comment: simply use nhibernate with connection to your DB on the backend, and not on the frontend...

Comment: I can not - DB is directly accessible only from that computer (one with DB service), not from mine.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, IDBDriver is used to establish connections and execute queries. If so, you do not need to use IDbDriver with NHibernate, because ISessionFactory and ISession do already what your IDbDriver does.